# How do I configure AWS Amplify to automatically add a new user to a group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've tried editing `GROUP` in

```
amplify/backend/function/<appnameXXXXX>PostConfirmation/function-parameters.json
```

followed by `amplify push` but that has no effect (and seems to leave the backend unchanged). I've tried editing the `GROUP` environment variable in the Lambda Console for `<appnameXXXXX>PostConfirmation-<env>` followed by `amplify pull`, which does update the local file above as expected, but new users are still not added to the specified group.

What am I doing wrong? How do I configure my app to automatically add a new user to a default group?

---

Relevant files, neither of which I've edited (except as noted for `GROUP` above):

function-parameters.json:

```js
{
  "trigger": true,
  "modules": [
    "add-to-group"
  ],
  "parentResource": "app_nameXXXXXX",
  "functionName": "app_nameXXXXXXPostConfirmation",
  "resourceName": "app_nameXXXXXXPostConfirmation",
  "parentStack": "auth",
  "triggerEnvs": [],
  "triggerDir": "/snapshot/repo/build/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-auth/provider-utils/awscloudformation/triggers/PostConfirmation",
  "triggerTemplate": "PostConfirmation.json.ejs",
  "triggerEventPath": "PostConfirmation.event.json",
  "roleName": "app_nameXXXXXXPostConfirmation",
  "skipEdit": true,
  "GROUP": "Testers",
  "enableCors": false
}
```

src/add-to-group.js:

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
});

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').PostConfirmationTriggerHandler}
 */
exports.handler = async event => {
  const groupParams = {
    GroupName: process.env.GROUP,
    UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
  };
  const addUserParams = {
    GroupName: process.env.GROUP,
    UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
    Username: event.userName,
  };
  /**
   * Check if the group exists; if it doesn't, create it.
   */
  try {
    await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getGroup(groupParams).promise();
  } catch (e) {
    await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.createGroup(groupParams).promise();
  }
  /**
   * Then, add the user to the group.
   */
  await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(addUserParams).promise();

  return event;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `amplify update function` command to manage your function's env variables.

Which will add corresponding configs in, `amplify/team-provider-info.json` and your lambda functions's `cloudformation` template json file.

---

This is how the command generate the ENV variable.

`Lambda function's cloudformation-template.json`

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    ...
    "GROUP": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    ...
  },
  "Resources": {
    ...
    "LambdaFunction": {
      ...
      "Properties": {
        ...
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "GROUP": {
              "Ref": "GROUP"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`team-provider-info.json`

```
{
  "dev": {
    "categories": {
      "function": {
        "<function-name>": {
          "GROUP": "users",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically I was editing the wrong files locally (and irrelevant configurations in the console)?

Comment: yeah, mhm, even from Lambda Console, any added ENV won't be pulled to your backend. But it still persists if you won't change via config or `amplify-cli`.

Comment: I'm confused about (a) where config info actually resides and (b) where and how to make changes. This are two pretty big problems! And they apply across all of Amplify. What I want to know is: where are the files (in one place I hope) that defines my "infrastructure as code" and how do I ensure they are in synch with the deployed backend. (And for that matter, why are the SO many files added to my client repo that are not those things?)

Comment: If I do the above Amplify clearly _tries_ at least, but fails with "not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:CreateGroup on resource ... because no identity-based policy allows the cognito-idp:CreateGroup action"; but the group is already there.

Comment: Um, I might be wrong but. a) `amplify-cli` basically makes managing CloudFormation template easy by bunch of commands. b) So for this Lambda function, config files are the CloudFormation template json file inside Lambda function directory itself. You can manage ENV, Policies etc. 

For each `push/deployment`, you files are uploaded to S3 bucket then CloudFormation stacks are created. And using that bucket, I think it keep track of versioning etc.

Comment: Yah that's what I'd though (hoped) but there seem to be gaps.

Comment: I think, that was because your lambda function don't have permission to create Cognito group. If you go to your Lambda function's CloudFormation template, you will see `lambdaexecutionpolicy` and inside that `PolicyDocument`. You need to add policy in here.

Comment: If that's the case then what is the point of Amplify? Apparently I can configure things in Amplify (either CLI or console or Studio, each of which has different scopes and don't quite stay in sync, but that's another matter) but have failed to _fully_ configure them, which then requires wading around in full-on AWS; even for the most basic things, even for things that it claims to support. What am I missing?

Comment: Rant aside (sorry, I think _everyone_ is pissed off right now) in my `.../amplify/backend/awscloudformation/build/function/<appnameXXXXX>PostConfirmation/<appnameXXXXX>PostConfirmation-cloudformation-template.json`, `Resources.lambdaexecutionpolicy.PolicyDocument.Statement'` has
`{"Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents"], ...`.

Comment: Oh wait: There should be o need to create a group. The group in question already exists. So for some reason I'm getting an error that I can't create a group even though the group exists, and then the new user isn't added (but is created).

Comment: This is getting weirder. I can only update data models if I _delete_ the GROUP environment variable (and [I'm not the only one](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-adminui/issues/486#issue-1139213725)), but if I do that and and a new user signs up I get "PostConfirmation failed with error Missing required key 'GroupName" in params." But that key refers to `GroupName: process.env.GROUP`" — so how is `add-to-groups.js` supposed to work then?

Comment: And in my `function-parameters.json` I even have `"GROUP": "Testers"` (which would seem as about as explicit as it can get; but also`"environmentVariableList": []`).

Comment: @orome did you ever figure this out? i have been banging my head against this same problem all night

Comment: @mlg87 It simply doesn't work as described. Support suggests jury-rigging a manually created function to add new users to groups, but in my experience any changes made to an Amplify app outside of Amplify will break all kinds of things (and require a complete from-scratch rebuild).

Comment: @orome [this is what you need](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2303#issuecomment-577790002). came across that about an hour ago and just got everything working in my setup. or, if you want a fast and dirty manual approach, [try this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7582#issuecomment-1133956864)